# Setting custom props on a dynamically created React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm refactoring some of my React code for ease of use in places where I can't use Babel directly (such as in short embedded JavaScript on pages). To assist with this I'm setting up a short function that builds the components and passes props to them. This code works just fine:

*components.js*:

```
import ResponsiveMenu from './components/responsive-menu';
window.setupMenu = (items, ele) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<ResponsiveMenu items={items}/>, ele);
};
```

*static-js.html*:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<script>
   setupMenu({ items: [] }, document.getElementById('menu');
</script>
```

However, when I attempt to turn it into something more generic to handle more components like so:

*components.js*:

```
import ResponsiveMenu from './components/responsive-menu';
import AnotherComp from './components/another-comp';

window.setupComponent = (selector, name, props) => {
  let eles;

  if (typeof selector == 'string') {
    eles = [];
    let nl = document.querySelectorAll(selector), node;
    for (let i = 0; node = nl[i]; i++) { eles.push(node); }
  } else {
    eles = $.toArray(selector); // A helper function that converts any value to an array.
  }

  return eles.map (
    (ele) => {
      let passProps = typeof props == 'function' ? props(ele) : props;
      return ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(name, passProps), ele);
    }
  );
};
```

*static-js.html*:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<script>
   setupComponent('#menu', 'ResponsiveMenu', { items: [] });
</script>
```

I then get this error: `Warning: Unknown prop "items" on <ResponsiveMenu> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see (really unhelpful shortened link that SO doesn't want me posting)`

Please help me understand why this works for the JSX version and not for the more manual version of creating the component.

Comment: The warning links me to this page, ultimately: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass string parameter to `React.createElement`, it will create native DOM element and there is no valid html DOM `ResponsiveMenu`.

You can store element into hash and store it into `window` variable.

Example:

```
// store component into window variable
window.components = {
     ResponsiveMenu: ResponsiveMenu
}

//extract component from window variable by name
React.createElement(window.components[name], passProps)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was beating my head against the wall for hours on this one!